# Is there any way to change the spawn location?

Tags: screeps

Currently a new creep will spawn one square above the spawn or in the next available clockwise position.

Is there any way to choose where newly created creeps go?

Answer (score 6):

In the newer api this can be done with `spawnCreep` by adding the optional parameter `directions`. This parameter accepts an array of preferred directions.

```
Game.spawns['Spawn1'].spawnCreep([WORK, CARRY, MOVE], 'Creep1', {
    directions: [TOP_RIGHT]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't but you can make it moving after it was created with a flag.

```
if(Game.flags.Flag1 !== undefined){
    creep.moveTo(Game.flags.Flag1);
}
```